# Add marker in MapBox Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, mapbox

I have two Activity. I want pass LatLng pass to another Activity.

```
This code in first Activity:
```

```
 public void testclick (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.putExtra("lat", "58.37");
        intent.putExtra("lan", "37.95");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

```
 What I must write in another Activity to get LaTLng?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", "`58.37`");
intent.putExtra("lan", "37.95")
startActivity(intent)
```

> ```
> And MainMenu Activity onCreate() method receive
> ```

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
String lat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
String lan = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lan");
```

}

Comment: very thx. One question again please)) How make getRoute?